# How to POST Form with three inputs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 inputs in a form.

```
Name:
Class:
Subject:
```

I have to take the input, call an API and do a post request like

```
{"Name":"hi","Class":"B","Subject":c}
```

How to do it in AngularJS?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please share your code!

Comment: `Angular !== AngularJS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess U should study more about forms and $http service but If I want to tell U how in the simplest way it would be sth like this: 
You probably have a controller Like "infoCtrl" or whatever you wish to call that which does all the logical work for your form View & you should have a submit function which is called upon form submission (ng-submit) and each of your form input probably has a ng-model value to bind them with your controller, so your form view & logic(controller) would be sth like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="infoCtrl">
    <form  name="info" ng-submit="infoSubmit()" >
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
        class: <input type="text" ng-model="className"/>
        subject: <input type="text" ng-model="subject"/>
        <button type="submit" >
             send
        </button>

    </form>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.infoSubmit = function () {
        let requestBody = {
            "name": $scope.name,
            "class": $scope.className,
            "subject":$scope.subject
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "Your_API_URL",
            data: requestBody
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            });
        }
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formController" ng-cloak>  
    <!--Form-->
    <form ng-submit="formData()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.name"" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Class</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.class"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.subject"/>
        </div>
      </div>      
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-show="submit" />  
      </div>
    </form>
    <!--End Form-->

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  //Buttons Settings
  $scope.submit = true;


  //form data manipulate
  $scope.formData = function() {

    //$http POST function
    $http({

      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://demoapi.com/formdata',
      data: $scope.data

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

      alert("created Successfully")

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

      alert("Error. while created user Try Again!");

    });

  };


}]);
```